# Best way to setup Git for multiple parallel and related projects

Tags: git

I'm currently maintaining multiple git repos that all are related to the same overall project. For simplicity, call them Hardware (HW), Software (SW), and User interface (UI). Since these are separate repos, a new feature that spanns multiple sub-projects must be committed separately in each repo. This makes it difficult to track changes across sub-project borders, and increases overhead work. What is a better git setup to facilitate full-stack development?

**Option 1:**
I have considered merging these into a Main repo, with each sub-project in a subfolder:

```
Main
\- HW
\- SW
\- UI
```

This way a single commit can affect all three parts. The only downside I see is that developers that only work on one sub-project must still checkout the full Main repo, then never touch the other folders.

**Option 2:**
I have also considered placing the three sub-projects as submodules in the Main project. This would allow a developer to checkout only the required sub-project. However, if I understand correctly, changes that span multiple sub-projects would still have to be committed separately in the submodules, thus loosing the benefit of a Main project. Please correct me if I'm wrong about this part.

So given this project structure and my two suggestions, which is considered the better choice? Or is there a third option that would work even better? I'm currently favoring option 1 to have the more directly connected structure, but any opinions are welcome.

Comment: Which is the tastier flavor of ice cream, chocolate or strawberry?

Comment: @torek, sure there are pros and cons with both, that's why I asked. But even if it might come down to personal preference I think the question is valid. If so, what's your preference based on experience? Help me learn something and avoid future pitfalls.

Comment: I've worked with it both ways. I *generally* prefer the monorepo myself, but there are always tradeoffs. It's really quite an opinion thing. Submodules can work in theory but I hate them :-)